# Notificaciones al cargar aplicación Laravel con VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web en Laravel, VueJS y MariaDB.

Compile los archivos .css y .js además del app.js donde ya inclui VueJS.

Pero se estan generando estas 3 notificaciones:

PRIMERA NOTIFICACIÓN:

You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html app.js:44539:45

SEGUNDA NOTIFICACIÓN:

Un XMLHttpRequest síncrono en el hilo principal está desaprobado por sus efectos negativos en la experiencia del usuario final. Para más ayuda vea  http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/ pace.min.js:2:6404

TERCERA NOTIFICACIÓN:

Error en el mapeo fuente: request failed with status 404
URL del recurso: http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js
URL del mapa fuente: bootstrap.js.map[Saber más]

De momento no me estan generando errores en la aplicación pero no se si quizás durante el desarrollo me pueda afectar.

Saben como puedo solucionarlos???

Comment: SIp.. solamente tenes que seguir los pasos que indican los links. Tuviste algun problema particular con alguno de ellos?

Comment: Por los momentos no, pero tuve que comenzar de nuevo a preparar y configurar todo pues hubo ocasiones donde me generaban otros errores sobre todo con el archivo app.js